# How did the connotations of "sabotage" evolve from "sabot", a type of shoe?

Tags: étymologie

My understanding is that the "sabot" was a kind of shoe. In English, there is a proverb "to throw a monkey wrench, into something," i.e. to "sabotage" it. Could there be a French proverb that uses a "sabot" as a version of a "monkey wrench"?

Another possibility comes from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabot), where a sabot is a projectile, which makes more sense, but which doesn't quite square with what I know of the word having been introduced around the time of the Industrial Revolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explanation I know makes it come from the wooden shoe and printing jargon.
At some time, the used, faulty letters were thrown away in a sabot or similar bucket.

The verb "saboter" then meant "to voluntarily throw away a perfectly working piece in the sabot", whence the current connotations.

This also gives an upper-bound for the origin of the word.

Answer (score 7):

Le nom *sabotage* vient de *saboter*.

D'après le « Dictionnaire historique de la langue française » (s.l.d. d'Alain Rey) en ancien français le verbe *saboter*  voulait dire *secouer*, *maltraiter*, et c'est peut-être de là que serait dérivé le sens actuel de *détruire*.

---

The noun *sabotage* comes from the verb *saboter*.

According to the «Dictionnaire Historique de la langue français » (under the direction of Alain Rey) in old French *saboter* had the meaning of *abuse*, *ill-treat*.  The present sense of *destroy* could very well come from that.

Answer (score 1):

Saboter est aussi beaucoup utilisé à la télévision télévision en France pour parler des actions des résistants pendant la seconde guerre mondiale.

---

*Saboter* is often used to report WW II resistance operations in France, especially in TV documentaries.