# Comment traduire « to throw a monkey wrench into » avec l'animé et l'inanimé ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

L'expression idiomatique « to throw a monkey wrench into » a déjà été abordée sous l'angle de l'[étymologie](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1521/25619). Voici deux exemples d'emploi :

> The boss *threw a [monkey wrench](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monkey_wrench) into* our plans when he said we'd have
> to work Saturday. ([tFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+a+monkey+wrench+into))
> We had everything in line for the party, but having the caterer cancel
> on us at the last minute really *threw a monkey wrench into our plans*! ([tFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+a+monkey+wrench+into))

Dans le premier exemple, le sujet est une personne (*the boss*) ; dans le deuxième cas, il s'agit d'une situation (*having the caterer cancel on us at the last minute* ; le fait que le traiteur ait annulé à la dernière minute).

Comment traduit-on la locution et pourquoi la traduit-on de la même manière ou non dans les deux cas ? A-t-on une expression idiomatique équivalente ? Si on utilise un nom, peut-on porter une attention particulière au(x) verbe(s) qui l'introduit et expliquer la formulation idiomatique ?

Answer (score 1):

Il n'existe rien qui approche une clef à molette simiesque...

En plus de la traduction la plus courante, *saboter*, voici deux suggestions pour traduire cette expression par une autre locution idiomatique :

> [Foutre en l'air](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/16702)

> Faire tomber [à l'eau](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/50996)

Ex.:

> Le chef a fait tomber notre projet à l'eau quand il a dit qu'on devrait bosser samedi.

> Tout était prêt pour la fête, mais que le traiteur ait tout annulé à la dernière minute a foutu nos plans/notre projet en l'air.

Les deux dernier peuvent s'employer indifféremment pour des personnes ou des situations, le verbe *saboter* s'emploie normalement pour des personnes car un sabotage est plus souvent intentionnel qu'accidentel mais on le rencontre pour autre chose, peut-être plus souvent en français canadien :

> On devait y aller dimanche passé mais la pluie a saboté nos plans. Je pense que c'était notre dernière chance. ([source](https://www.motoneigeauquebec.com/forum/showthread.php?220144-Accident-%E0-H%E9bertville))

> L'hiver a été rude et la grêle a saboté les jardins des maraîchers. ([source](https://bibliotheques.cc-sevreloire.fr/notices/colas-veut-prendre-la-bastille))

Comment: Merci, excellent.

Comment: À noter que *foutre en l'air* est très familier, et que *foutre la merde dans* l'est encore plus

Comment: @NinoFiliu Je dirais juste familier plutôt que très mais tout est relatif. L'Académie va encore plus loin que toi et déconseille l'innocent *ficher en l'air*...